# Inserting JsonObject to Bigquery gives null

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to insert a TableRow into BigQuery that have a column of type [Record] which is "readposts" but the values of "readposts.id" are null;

**Schema**

```
List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("userid").setType("STRING"));

TableFieldSchema column2 = new TableFieldSchema().setName("readposts");
column2.setType("RECORD");
List<TableFieldSchema> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("id").setType("STRING"));
column2.setFields(list2);
column2.setMode("REPEATED");
fields.add(column2);

return new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
```

**Code**

```
JSONArray rawFields =new JSONArray();
rawFields.put(new JSONObject().put("id", "post1"));
rawFields.put(new JSONObject().put("id", "post2"));
row.set("readposts", rawFields);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use TableRowJsonCoder and it works

```
    return rows.setCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of());
```